# where is the submit value from in this form?

Tags: php

I got this script:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST) || empty($_POST)) {
    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="textfield"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    $roughHTTPPOST = readfile("php://input");
    echo $roughHTTPPOST;
}
?>
```

Every time I submit the form I get a string contain both textfield and Submit value, the textfield value is pretty simple and straighforward. However I don't know where te Submit value come from?
Here is a sample string return when I enter "a" character and submit form:

> textfield=a&Submit=Submit25
>   P/S: What I mean here is the value **25** appended after 'Submit', where does it come from, the textfield value is easy to understand.

Comment: It's coming from your submit button. Try removing the name="Submit".

Comment: from here: `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: don't test $_POST like that. it's unreliable. use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` instead. that's 100% reliable.

Comment: Agreed, but it's strange why there is a `25` appended to it...

Comment: @MrXenotype A typo or some further URL manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `25` gets appended because that's the return value of `readfile()`, i.e. the number of bytes that were read from `php://input`.

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

That would give the expected output.

---

The value of `Submit=Submit` simply comes from your markup:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

If you wish to remove that, simply delete the `name` attribute and the browser won't send it.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from:

```
... name="Submit" ...
```

Comment: And to add, this is good if you have multiple submit buttons with different values for different purpose, like for example making a calculator

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @vanneto How does it not answer the question?

Comment: I though the problem he was facing was the 25 in which case it really doesn't. Now I'm not so sure what he means.

Comment: @vanneto I'm sure that you've tested the code yourself and determined that it's because of the behavior of `readfile("php://input");`.

Comment: Yes, I tested it carefully, I saw different results. When I enter 'ab' (or 'ad' or '12' etc..) into the input field it returns 'Submit26' and if I enter 'abc' it returns 'Submit27'. and yeah you're right, because readfile return the number of bytes read from file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php